# how can we customize graphite to support xml format?

Tags: graphite

graphite support json and csv, but how we customize it to support other formats,

this works example:

```
 10.1.2.15:8080/render?target=testing1.counters.hello.rate&format=json&from=-5min

  10.1.2.15:8080/render?target=testing1.counters.hello.rate&format=csv&from=-5min
```

i want to get a xml report by passing the format like below, is it possible?

example:

```
10.1.2.15:8080/render?target=testing1.counters.hello.rate&format=xml&from=-5min
```

Comment: @MattSelf please suggest something on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask the [project](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web) themselves and file an issue or better Pull Request providing the required functionality if it's currently missing from this open source project.

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper. Here is the discussion on adding a custom API end to Graphite.

https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/147349